# Angular2 : How to pass value through a form to another component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I'm new to Angular2 and i would like to do something simple :

1. Submit a form to make an order.
2. Save the order via an external API into database
3. Go to the payment page while keeping the order object

**My first question** : After saving how can I pass object to the other page ?

**My second question** : Am i even doing this whole "form thing" in the best way ?

form.html

```
<form [formGroup]="orderForm" #formDir="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(formDir.value)">
    [...]
</form>
```

form.component

```
submitForm(): void {
    this.orderService.saveOrder(this.order)
        .then(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/payment', ['order', this.order]));
}
```

paymentComponent

```
order: Order;

constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.order = params['order'];
    });
}
```

Comment: You have to specify a route that receives order as parameter.

Comment: You can pass value to other component by using @Input or use a shared service. If you share your html structure, we can help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After saving how can I pass object to the other page ?

After form save operation completes, return a current saved order object from API and then while redirecting pass `order.id` which has been saved in DB. Also make sure you have `order` parameter mention in the route parameter of route definition.

```
submitForm(): void {
    this.orderService.saveOrder(this.order)
        .then((savedOrderObj) => this.router.navigateByUrl('/payment', ['order', savedOrderObj.id]));
}
```

> Am i even doing this whole "form thing" in the best way ?

Yes, it seems correct. While navigating to route you're passing `order`(id) parameter. So the `paymentComponent` component can retrieve that Order based on `order` parameter passed to the route.

You should consider moving `routeParams` subscription code to `ngOnInit` hook, as constructor shouldn't have any startup logic. Create a `OrderService` which would be thoroughly responsible for retrieving `order` data. It can have different method, one of them could be retrieving data based on id.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private orderService: OrderService) {
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.orderService.getOrderById(params['order']).subscribe(
           (order) => this.order = order
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: @omeralper I will always trust whatever have been saved in DB. I don't like to be too smart. If one ajax call is going to provide me more data consistency, then it worth making it(rather it could take few ms)

Comment: If you have a dynamic page with fast page transitions, miliseconds are important.

Comment: @omeralper Are you serious you still wanted to do that.? Keeping Application state locally and retrieving it back is good, but waiting for 10-100ms does matter for me If I'm gonna get data consistency.

Comment: does not matter*

Answer (score 0):

@omeralper's comment is correct you need to use a service to pass complex data types like an object literal, or any data that you don't want to be displayed in the URL, which is what happens with params.

**Data Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 
export class DataService {
  data: {[key: string]: any}; 
}
```

**Component X**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component() 
export class X {

  get data(): {[key: string]: any}{ 
    return this.dataService.data; 
  }

  set data(value: {[key: string]: any}) { 
    this.dataService.data = value; 
  } 

  constructor(public dataService: DataService) { } 

  submitForm(): void {
    this.dataService.set(this.order); // Store order for use by next component
    this.orderService.saveOrder(this.order)
      .then(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/y'));
  }
}
```

**Component Y**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component() 
export class Y { 

  data: { [key: string]: any };

  get data(): {[key: string]: any}{ 
    return this.dataService.data; 
  } 

  set data(value: {[key: string]: any}) { 
    this.dataService.data = value; 
  } 

  constructor(public dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.dataService.get(); // Route component loads and you retrieve the data
  }
}
```

You'll want to beef up the service, and maybe call it `RouteDataService`, but this will allow for inter-component communications.

You don't want to make another request if you already have the data available.  Doing it once or twice doesn't hurt, but as your application grows making this your strategy will degrade performance.

Otherwise, I prefer reactive forms over template driven forms to keep the logic in the controller and the complexity of the template down, but you're not doing anything wrong that's just a preference.  If you haven't checked out reactive forms yet this is a decent intro [tutorial](https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-reactive#reactive-approach) for you to compare both.